# Parallel processing for a List

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, .net-3.5

My scenario:
I need to process a list of elements. Each element processing is highly time consuming (1-10 seconds)
Instead of a

```
List retval = new List();
foreach (item in myList)
    retval.Add(ProcessItem(item));
return retval;
```

I want to parallel process each item.

I know .NET has got a number of approach for parallel processing: what is the best one? (note, I'm stuck to 3.5 framework version, cannot use Task, async and all nancy features coming with .Net 4...)

Here my try using delegates:

```
private void DoTest(int processingTaskDuration)
{
    List<int> itemsToProcess = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        itemsToProcess.Add(i);

    TestClass tc = new TestClass(processingTaskDuration);

    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    List<int> result = tc.ProcessList(itemsToProcess);
    TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - start;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("elapsed (msec)= {0}", (int)elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
}

public class TestClass
{
    static int s_Counter = 0;
    static object s_lockObject = new Object();

    int m_TaskMsecDuration = 0;
    public TestClass() :
        this(5000)
    {
    }

    public TestClass(int taskMsecDuration)
    {
        m_TaskMsecDuration = taskMsecDuration;
    }


    public int LongOperation(int itemToProcess)
    {
        int currentCounter = 0;
        lock (s_lockObject)
        {
            s_Counter++;
            currentCounter = s_Counter;
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("LongOperation\tStart\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", currentCounter, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff")));

        // time consuming task, e.g 5 seconds
        Thread.Sleep(m_TaskMsecDuration);
        int retval = itemToProcess * 2;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("LongOperation\tEnd  \t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", currentCounter, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff")));
        return retval;
    }

    delegate int LongOperationDelegate(int itemToProcess);
    public List<int> ProcessList(List<int> itemsToProcess)
    {
        List<IAsyncResult> asyncResults = new List<IAsyncResult>();
        LongOperationDelegate del = LongOperation;

        foreach (int item in itemsToProcess)
        {
            IAsyncResult res = del.BeginInvoke(item, null, null);
            asyncResults.Add(res);
        }

        // list of waitHandles to wait for
        List<WaitHandle> waitHandles = new List<WaitHandle>();
        asyncResults.ForEach(el => waitHandles.Add(el.AsyncWaitHandle));


        // wait for processing every item
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles.ToArray());


        // retrieve result of processing
        List<int> retval = new List<int>();
        asyncResults.ForEach(res =>
        {
            int singleProcessingResult = del.EndInvoke(res);
            retval.Add(singleProcessingResult);
        }
        );
        return retval;
    }
}
```

And thats some output (column #3 is a progressive counter, use it to match start with end of a call, #4 is threadID and last is a timeStamp)

```
LongOperation   Start   1   6   15:11:18.331619
LongOperation   Start   2   12  15:11:18.331619
LongOperation   Start   3   13  15:11:19.363722
LongOperation   Start   4   14  15:11:19.895775
LongOperation   Start   5   15  15:11:20.406826
LongOperation   Start   6   16  15:11:21.407926
LongOperation   Start   7   17  15:11:22.410026
LongOperation   End     1   6   15:11:23.360121
LongOperation   End     2   12  15:11:23.361122
LongOperation   Start   8   12  15:11:23.363122
LongOperation   Start   9   6   15:11:23.365122
LongOperation   Start   10  18  15:11:23.907176
LongOperation   End     3   13  15:11:24.365222
LongOperation   Start   11  13  15:11:24.366222
LongOperation   End     4   14  15:11:24.897275
LongOperation   Start   12  14  15:11:24.898275
LongOperation   Start   13  19  15:11:25.407326
LongOperation   End     5   15  15:11:25.408326
LongOperation   Start   14  15  15:11:25.412327
LongOperation   Start   15  20  15:11:26.407426
LongOperation   End     6   16  15:11:26.410426
LongOperation   Start   16  16  15:11:26.410426
LongOperation   Start   17  21  15:11:27.408526
LongOperation   End     7   17  15:11:27.411527
LongOperation   Start   18  17  15:11:27.413527
LongOperation   End     8   12  15:11:28.365622
LongOperation   Start   19  12  15:11:28.366622
LongOperation   End     9   6   15:11:28.366622
LongOperation   Start   20  6   15:11:28.389624
LongOperation   End     10  18  15:11:28.908676
LongOperation   End     11  13  15:11:29.367722
LongOperation   End     12  14  15:11:29.899775
LongOperation   End     13  19  15:11:30.411827
LongOperation   End     14  15  15:11:30.413827
LongOperation   End     15  20  15:11:31.407926
LongOperation   End     16  16  15:11:31.411927
LongOperation   End     17  21  15:11:32.413027
LongOperation   End     18  17  15:11:32.416027
LongOperation   End     19  12  15:11:33.389124
LongOperation   End     20  6   15:11:33.391124
elapsed (msec)= 15075
```

So:

Is Delegate approach the right one?

Did I implement it right?

If so, why the 3rd operations starts one second after the first two (and so on)?

I mean, I'd like the whole processing complete in more or less the time of one single processing, but it seems the system uses thread pool in a strange way. After all, I'm asking 20 threads, and it waits to span the 3rd one just after the first two calls.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti the OP said he is stuck with .NET 3.5, Paralle.ForEach is a .NET 4.0 and up feature.

Comment: @MPatel you're right

Comment: Just noted a (further) problem with my implementation:
the WaitHandle.WaitAll accept a maximum of 64 WaitHandle, which means that's the limit of the number of items in list I can process in this way.

But anyway, the big problem is that the "paralleling" is not so "paralleling": in my sample, instead of something more than 5 seconds total time I'm expecting, I get 15 :(

Comment: The fact that you have use a lock object in Longoperation renders parallel processing obsolete. You have to keep in mind that every time a thread hits the lock, if it is in lock mode than the thread will wait until it is released.

Comment: The lock there is just for protecting the shared s_counter variable while incrementing it within the lock: each thread will get the lock and release it almost immediatly.

I made further test: using or not using a lock within the LongOperation doesn't change the total time of the ProcessList.

Comment: But while testing I got a surprise: first time a call the ProcessList method, thread are spawned with delay from each other.

But in further calls, the delay between thread decrease, and after a few test they all start at same time: it seems the ThreadPool has "plenty" of available thread now and the method works as expected.

Do you think I'm on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of my third question:

> If so, why the 3rd operations starts one second after the first two
>   (and so on)?

The problem seems to be in the default way ThreadPool manages thread spawning: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y%28v=VS.90%29.aspx. Quote:

> The thread pool has a built-in delay (half a second in the .NET
>   Framework version 2.0) before starting new idle threads. If your
>   application periodically starts many tasks in a short time, a small
>   increase in the number of idle threads can produce a significant
>   increase in throughput. Setting the number of idle threads too high
>   consumes system resources needlessly.

It seems a call to ThreadPool.SetMinThreads with a proper value helps a lot.
At the start of my ProcessList, I inserted a call to this method:

```
private void SetUpThreadPool(int numThreadDesired)
{
    int currentWorkerThreads;
    int currentCompletionPortThreads;
    ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out currentWorkerThreads, out currentCompletionPortThreads);
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ThreadPool.GetMinThreads: workerThreads = {0}, completionPortThreads = {1}", workerThreads, completionPortThreads));

    const int MAXIMUM_VALUE_FOR_SET_MIN_THREAD_PARAM = 20;
    int numMinThreadToSet = Math.Min(numThreadDesired, MAXIMUM_VALUE_FOR_SET_MIN_THREAD_PARAM);
    if (currentWorkerThreads < numMinThreadToSet)
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(numThreadDesired, currentCompletionPortThreads);
}

public List<int> ProcessList(List<int> itemsToProcess)
{
    SetUpThreadPool(documentNumberList.Count);
    ...
}
```

Now all thread (up to 20) start at the same moment, without delay. I think 20 is a good compromise for MAXIMUM_VALUE_FOR_SET_MIN_THREAD_PARAM: not too hight, and fits my particular requirements

Still wondering about main questions

> > 1. Is Delegate approach the right one?
> > 2. Did I implement it right?

Thanks to everyone helping.

Answer (score 2):

I think [the 3.5 backport of Reactive Extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24940) comes with an implementation of `Parallel.ForEach()` that you should be able to use.  The port should just contain *only* what was needed to get Rx to work on 3.5, but that should be enough.

Others [have tried](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48804/implementation-of-parallel-foreach-for-net-3-5) implementing it [as well](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/webdev/serverprogramming/a-simple-parallel-foreach-implementation-5/), basically just queuing work items on `ThreadPool`.

Comment: I installed RX for .Net 3.5 and added a reference to System.Reactive to my project, but I can't find any "Parallel" to use.

First time I hear about RX: I'm googling around, still don't understand how should I use it for parallel processing

Comment: @GianPaolo: It's entirely possible that I'm mis-remembering, and unfortunately I don't have a pre-4.0 environment handy to accurately confirm this.  If it turns out I'm incorrect, I'll gladly delete the answer.

Comment: I switched my test project to framework 4 and found the Parallel class: it seems it's available only in the framework version I cannot use in my real code :( Thanks anyway

Comment: I tested the Parallel approach with this code:


    public List<int> ProcessList2(List<int> itemsToProcess)
    {
     List<int> result = new List<int>();
     var x = System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<int>(itemsToProcess, item => result.Add(LongOperation(item)));
     return result;
    }


Same problem that my delegate approach, with task starting with a delay and a total time of about 15 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<int>{ 1,2,3 };
    var processes = list.Count();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => {
            ProcessItem(item);      
            processes--;
        });
    }
    while (processes > 0) { Thread.Sleep(10); }
}

static void ProcessItem(int item)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100); // do work
}
```

Comment: In this way, I'm not able to retrive the result of process item (and also, I need to return to the caller when all processing is completed)

Comment: You should not be using busywaits to wait for the operations to finish.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. what do you mean with "busy waits"?

Each element of my list has to be processed, and return value for each processing has to be returned to the caller.

Comment: @GianPaolo busy wait is referring to 'while (processes > 0) { Thread.Sleep(10); }'. There is absolutely nothing worse than a while loop in this format. I would really be concerned if software I worked on contained code like this.

Comment: @MPatel I agree, I don't like the "sleep a while and check again" pattern. But the big problem with the above answer is that it works only if you don't care about "processItem" return value, which is actually what I have to return, in list, to the caller.